# Code duplication issue because capturing lambdas cannot decay to function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I am interfacing with some 3rd party data structures which store raw data in a `std::vector<std::uint8_t> data` and has many lightweight `field` structures describing the data type and offset.

I have a repeating pattern in my code which looks a bit like this:

```
*reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[i + field.offset]) = some_value;
```

Here `T` is some type that must match `field.datatype`, which I can check through with `asEnum<T>::value == field.datatype`.

I need to perform these access operations many times, for various `i`.

To make the code more readable, I can check for validity then define a lambda before modifying the data:

```
if (asEnum<T>::value != field.datatype) {
    throw std::runtime_error("datatype did not match type T");
}
const std::size_t offset = field.offset;
auto field_access_func = [offset](const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data, const std::size_t i) -> T& {
    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[i + offset]);
};

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    field_access_func(data, i) = some_value;
}
```

I need help packaging this functionality up into a function.

It would be really convenient to pack this functionality into a function like this:

```
template<typename T>
using FieldAccessFunction = T& (*)(const std::vector<std::uint8_t>&, const std::size_t);

template<typename T>
FieldAccessFunction<T> create_access_function(const FieldStruct& field) {
    if (asEnum<T>::value != field.datatype) {
         throw std::runtime_error("datatype did not match type T");
    }
    const std::size_t offset = field.offset;
    return [offset](const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data, const std::size_t i) -> T& {
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[i + offset]);
    };
}
```

And then the processing code would be very readable and efficient:

```
auto a_field_access_func = create_access_function<double>(a_field);
auto b_field_access_func = create_access_function<float>(b_field);
auto c_field_access_func = create_access_function<bool>(c_field);
auto d_field_access_func = create_access_function<int>(d_field);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    a_field_access_func(data, i) = some_double;
    b_field_access_func(data, i) = some_float;
    c_field_access_func(data, i) = some_bool;
    d_field_access_func(data, i) = some_int;
}
```

However this is not possible, because a capturing lambda cannot decay to a function pointer. I also don't want to use `std::function` because this code needs to be efficient and many report on how `std::function` can have significant performance overhead.

I have considered passing the field as an argument to a templated access function, but don't see how to get around checking for type safety every single iteration:

```
template<typename T>
T& access_function(const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data, const std::size_t i, const FieldStruct& field) {
    if (asEnum<T>::value != field.datatype) {
         throw std::runtime_error("datatype did not match type T");
    }
    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[i + field.offset]);
}

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    access_func<double>(data, i, a_field) = some_double;
    access_func<float>(data, i, b_field) = some_float;
    access_func<bool>(data, i, c_field) = some_bool;
    access_func<int>(data, i, d_field) = some_int;
}
```

I cannot think of a good solution to this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not just return the closure object?  The return type of `create_access_function` can be `auto` and you can just return the closure object to the outside scope.

Comment: *...many report on how `std::function` can have significant performance overhead*  You'd have to **profile** the performance of using a `std::function` to see if the performance overhead is significant or not.  If you don't measure, you don't know.

Comment: Sometimes a bit of performance is a small price to pay for maintainability. Have you measured if using a std::function would even show up as a peformance bottleneck? It could well be that the way your data is oranized (or not) in memory that in the end will be a bigger problem. As said performance is all about measuring and understanding the whole system.

Comment: `*reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[i + field.offset]) = some_value;` looks like UB.

Comment: This is one of the examples that cries for cps. I can likely come up with an answer in a few mins.

Comment: @WillT Is it ok to have `FieldStruct` as constexpr or do you have (runtime) dynamic types?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are doing binary externalization to some third party format? If yes please provide specification of it, then someone will provide better solution then your approach or possibly ready library. Is this binary format in public domain? Note there are already some tools capable of doing all that without UB. For example in Qt there is QDataStream.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate on this with an example?

Comment: @Eljay that's a fair comment, but these functions will be called potentially millions of times per second, so any overhead is costly.

Comment: Change `template<typename T> FieldAccessFunction<T> create_access_function(const FieldStruct& field)` to `auto create_access_function(const FieldStruct& field)`.  That returns the closure object (the thing the lambda expression generates) without any sort of conversion.  It also allows you to keep the syntax of using `auto a_field_access_func = create_access_function<double>(a_field); ...; a_field_access_func(data, i) = some_double;`

Comment: @MarekR `std::vector` is contiguous so I don't think so provided the bounds of the data block aren't exceeded (i.e. `i + field.offset + sizeof(T)` isn't past the end of the vector's data.

Comment: @WillT The `i + field.offset + sizeof(T)` part is not the issue, it's the `reinterpret_cast`.  You don't have a `T`, you have a `char[N]` and treating a `char[N]` as a `T` violates strict aliasing and is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks I wasn't aware this was possible, i'll try that now and report back

Comment: @lorro `FieldStruct` can be defined as `struct FieldStruct { std::string name; std::size_t offset = 0; std::uint8_t datatype = 0; }`

Comment: @WillT Where does it come from? Is it loaded runtime, or do you have the fields compile-time? (Also, c++20 allows for `constexpr std::string`, but for earlier versions, perhaps a `const char*` would be better for you.)

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok I didn't realise this was UB. As far as I know and my unit tests are concerned this has been working fine until now, but it may not have been. It looks like maybe a better strategy is to copy the bytes directly rather than give myself a reference/pointer to the data directly which as you point out is invalid

Comment: @lorro the fields are not available at compile time, but loaded at runtime. I don't have write access of `FieldStruct`, that's part of the (no publically available) 3rd party library i'm interfacing with

Comment: @WillT Unfortunately that is the down side of undefined behavior.  Often times it works fine as most compilers do the "sane" thing.

Comment: For example this code will cash on ARM processors because of UB (alignment of `float`/`double`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @lorro for your detailed answer. `constexpr` is a useful concept I hadn't considered. However I've decided on a solution that is more in line with the suggestion by @NathanOliver to return the closure type to enable the capturing.

Thanks to @NathanOliver and @MarekR for pointing out the undefined behaviour from breaking strict aliasing.

The solution I have now I believe fixes both these issues, and I extended it to allow for any input type (and I had actually forgotten the step variable in my original post, which is now included).

```
template<typename InT, typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<InT, T>, int> = 0>
auto create_set_field_data_function(const FieldStruct& field, const std::size_t step) {
    if (asEnum<T>::value != field.datatype) {
        throw std::runtime_error("datatype did not match type T");
    }
    const std::size_t offset = field.offset;
    return [offset, step](std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data, const std::size_t i, const InT value) -> void {
        std::memcpy(&data[i * step + offset], &value, sizeof(T));
    };
}

template<typename InT, typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<InT, T>, int> = 0>
auto create_set_field_data_function(const FieldStruct& field, const std::size_t step) {
    if (asEnum<T>::value != field.datatype) {
        throw std::runtime_error("datatype did not match type T");
    }
    const std::size_t offset = field.offset;
    return [offset, step](std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data, const std::size_t i, const InT value_in) -> void {
        const T value = static_cast<T>(value_in);
        std::memcpy(&data[i * step + offset], &value, sizeof(T));
    };
}
```

I can even add a specialisation for the simple `std::uint8_t` case:

```
template<>
auto create_set_field_data_function<std::uint8_t, std::uint8_t>(const FieldStruct& field, const std::size_t step) {
    if (asEnum<std::uint8_t>::value != field.datatype) {
        throw std::runtime_error("datatype did not match type std::uint8_t");
    }
    const std::size_t offset = field.offset;
    return [offset, step](std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data, const std::size_t i, const std::uint8_t value) -> void {
        data[i * step + offset] = value;
    };
}
```

And I can create a function overload to allow the type to be determined at runtime. Here a helper function is needed, because only one lambda can be returned from a function (each has a unique type):

```
template<typename InT>
using SetFieldDataFunctionHelper = void (*)(std::vector<std::uint8_t>&, const std::size_t, const std::size_t, const std::size_t, const InT);

template<typename InT, typename T>
SetFieldDataFunctionHelper<InT> create_set_field_data_function_helper(const FieldStruct& field) {
    return [](std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data, const std::size_t i, const std::size_t offset, const std::size_t step, const InT value_in) -> void {
        const T value = static_cast<T>(value_in);
        std::memcpy(&data[i * step + offset], &value, sizeof(T));
    };
}

template<typename InT>
auto create_set_field_data_function(const FieldStruct& field) {
    SetFieldDataFunctionHelper<InT> helper;
    switch (field.datatype) {
        case FLOAT32:
            helper = create_set_field_data_function_helper<InT, asType<FLOAT32>::type>(field);
            break;
        case FLOAT64:
            helper = create_set_field_data_function_helper<InT, asType<FLOAT64>::type>(field);
            break;
        case INT8:
            ... // create helper for each type
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("field datatype not recognised");
    }
    const std::size_t offset = field.offset;
    return [helper, offset, step](std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data, const std::size_t i, const InT value) -> void {
        return helper(data, i, offset, step, value);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to make `FieldStruct` (or an appropriate restriction of it that has `offset` and `datatype` in it) `constexpr`. That way, you can decide *based on the `FieldStruct` received* which data type you'd like to use (thus you can save the exception path). I'm posting an example below, but before that, a big fat warning:

Aliasing fields via reinterpret cast might cause troubles. Esp. if you have anything more complex than POD types. Esp. if you write to them, then read it via another variable. It is suggested that you always consult your sw architect / standard-aware person before doing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

enum DataType {
    e_double,
    e_float,
    e_bool,
    e_int
};

struct FieldStruct {
    DataType datatype;
    size_t offset;
};

struct Data {
    int i;
    bool b;
};

template<FieldStruct fs, typename FN>
auto with_field(char* dataptr, FN fn)
{
    // note: I'm following your pattern here for understandability
    // ideally, you'd memcpy() it to a given type.
    char* fieldptr = dataptr + fs.offset;
    if constexpr (fs.datatype == e_double) {
        return fn(*reinterpret_cast<double*>(fieldptr));
    } else if constexpr (fs.datatype == e_float) {
        return fn(*reinterpret_cast<float*>(fieldptr));
    } else if constexpr (fs.datatype == e_bool) {
        return fn(*reinterpret_cast<bool*>(fieldptr));
    } else if constexpr (fs.datatype == e_int) {
        return fn(*reinterpret_cast<int*>(fieldptr));
    }
}

int main()
{
    Data d{6, true};
    constexpr FieldStruct d_i{e_int,  offsetof(Data, i)};
    constexpr FieldStruct d_b{e_bool, offsetof(Data, b)};
    
    char* dataptr = reinterpet_cast<char*>(&d);  // obviously, don't do this in prod
    // note that data type is deduced automatically for the call
    with_field<d_i>(dataptr, [&](auto& val) {
        val = 12;
    });
    
    std::cout << d.i;
}
```

Of course, you might adjust the code to tie multiple such `FieldStruct` items to a compile-time tuple and have access to multiple variables in your lambda if you'd like.